# How to wrap accordion pairs with outer container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have the following problem with the accordion. I have pairs of elements with an outer container "accordion" but I need to wrap each pair with another container. As I understood I can't wrap them before because the accordion won't work.

So I need to wrap them after domready with an additional snippet...

I got this:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h2 class="head">Headline</h2>
    <div class="content">Some content...</div>
    <h2 class="head">Headline</h2>
    <div class="content">Some content...</div>
 ....more pairs
</div>
```

I need this:

```
<div id="accordion">
<div class="outer">
    <h2 class="head">Headline</h2>
    <div class="content">Some content...</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <h2 class="head">Headline</h2>
    <div class="content">Some content...</div>
</div>
...more pairs
</div>
```

I thought this will do the job:

```
$('.head').before('<div class="outer">');
$('.content').after('</div>');
```

...but it inserts already closed divs before each headline.

Comment: simple create your own html structure and use header option like
   header: '> div.outer> h2'

I am also wanted the same structure but also wanted to addclass to outer div if accordion is active and remove class from outer if it is not active

Answer (score 5):

You can only insert whole elements using methods like `before()` and `after()`.

One way to achieve what you want would be to call [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) on each `<h2>`/`<div>` pair, using something like [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to match the pairs:

```
$("#accordion h2").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("h2").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='outer'></div>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint...but this doesn´t work...i modified it a bit and now it does what i wanted: 
    $("#accordion").find('.head').each(function() {
        $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='outer'></div>");
    });

Comment: Interesting, `next()` and `nextUntil("h2")` should be equivalent given the markup in your question. I doesn't matter however, since you now have a working solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('.head:first,.content:first').wrapAll('<div class="outer">');
  $('.head:last,.content:last').wrapAll('<div class="outer">');
```

JSFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sanooj/YnE2c/1/)